# Effect of bluetooth headphones on health

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, biology, medical-physics

There was an article on the internet assuming that there's a high chance that bluetooth headphones cause a lot of mental and physical damages to our body. They explained it in a pretty neat way if I understood it correctly. They said as bluetooth headphones are the second class of waves, which have about 10 meters of effection area and average amount of effect, they are capable enough to damage a flow in body. As they have a fairly high energy, and as electrical flows in our body or more primary than chemical flows, the magnetic field causes by the headphones affects the electrical flows in body and disrupts them causing several problems in our body. Is this explanation right? Do you know any trust worthy articles I can read to know how bad bluetooth is for humans? Also do the same things apply to wifi waves too? Thanks in advance for any help.

Link:

https://www.radiationhealthrisks.com/bluetooth-technology-radiation/

Comment: *They explained it in a pretty neat way if I understood it correctly.* Who are **they**?

Comment: No one here will judge that w/o a link to the source material.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.radiationhealthrisks.com/bluetooth-technology-radiation/&ved=2ahUKEwiX6_2UqMLnAhVKl4sKHVKPDt4QFjANegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3oDYf-qZm7dndE5BSv_H13

Comment: *the higher the frequency, the more dangerous it is to living organisms...* Visible light has a higher frequency than the RF signals used in these devices, so the frequency argument is obviously a poor one.

Comment: RadiationHealthRisks.com is by no means a peer reviewed publication. Instead it's a banal clickbaity 'health resource', like there are 13 in a dozen. Stay well clear: the BS content is likely very high!

Comment: First off, that blog is dangerously pseudoscientific and I would strongly advise you stay away from such unconventional sources since they typically have far-flung theories which end-up causing more harm than good. It's much better to stay within accepted medicine, the acepted beliefs will not be up-to-date with the latest research but wont be nearly as harmfull as pseudoscience and random bloggers.

Comment: Secondly, yours is not a Physics question as much as a health question. I recommend you go to the Medical Sciences StackExchange website. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I though this would have some connection with wave studies in physics. Thanks for the tip I will post the question there too

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking a question about physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So physics only has a very little bit to say about this topic.

Obviously, if there is a very large circuit, you can induce electrical currents in it with radio and microwaves—if this weren't true, your radio would not work. However, this has to be understood as a bulk motion of a lot of electrons over the wavelength of the wave, and so in terms of biological structures, if we take the typical biological structure as a cell of 100 microns, this starts to be an issue at frequencies of 3 terahertz or above. At frequencies much lower than that like Bluetooth (2.4 GHz, I think?), the internal function of the cell is not so much being disturbed, but possibly a larger jiggling of a bunch of cells all together in an organ is possible. As you get larger, the danger would apparently get lower: your body might have limited resources to regulate a cell, but it has a whole circulatory system to cool down a warm liver.

In addition, as those frequencies get even higher, a new effect starts to appear: electromagnetic waves start to become chemically active due to quantum mechanics. The bonds that bind together molecules have a certain energy per bond, and quantum mechanics says that an individual particle of light has a certain kick to it, and we can ask when those energies are of the same scale. This turns out to be at the very high frequencies (petahertz) that you see in visible light for example: visible light is chemically active and that is why we have receptors to see it!

As you go higher and higher in frequency, you get to ultraviolet rays, x-rays, and gamma rays. These are so chemically active, they have so much kick, that they can be powerful enough to disrupt the chemical bonds that are in your body, in particular they can potentially break apart DNA, which is thought to be a mechanism by which these rays cause mass cell death (sunburns) and occasionally mess with the wrong parts of the DNA to create mutant cells that do not stop replicating (cancer).

It is extremely unlikely that Bluetooth is carcinogenic: the waves are just too big for that. People have worried about this for a long time, in the context of cell phone usage, and large studies have been carried out with no findings of a significant increase in cancer risk. For example a study [called Interphone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interphone_study) found that across most of their categories increase cell phone use was associated with *less* cancer which seemed strange.

With that said, we physicists would not be able to rule out more sophisticated interactions where your body works like some sort of antenna and responds in a sophisticated way to external microwaves and radio waves. That is the role for medical practitioners and researchers. I can design a circuit that sits on the back of a mouse and if I am cruel I can make it listen for a microwave signal and then dump toxins into that mouse’s bloodstream. Therefore, I as a physicist cannot prove that that is not what happens inside your body anywhere. It is physically possible for such mechanisms to exist, and we have nothing to say about them as physicists.

As a broader scientist, I can say that that sounds like a weird thing to evolve, but weird things do happen to evolve all the time, so I don't think that's necessarily a decisive argument against it.